# how to show current page num of paging scrollView?

Tags: react-native

ScrollView:

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
    <ScrollView
        ref={(component) => {this._scrollView = component}}
        scrollEventThrottle={15}
        removeClippedSubviews={true}
        pagingEnabled={true}
        horizontal={true}
        onScroll={this._onScroll.bind(this)}>
        {items}
   </ScrollView>
   <Text style={styles.legend}>{this.state.currentPage}/{9}</Text
</View>
```

`_onScroll`:this method calc what current page num is

```js
_onScroll(e) {
    let newPageNum = parseInt(e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x/WINDOW_WIDTH+1);

    newPageNum != this.state.currentPage && this.setState({
        currentPage: newPageNum
    });
}
```

I think the codeline is ok, but when I pan the `scrollView` to next page, it will scroll back. once I remove the codeline in `_onScroll`, the question can be solved, but I can't calc current page num.

Comment: This code is working for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer，you help me step out of my thinking's trap. And now I'm sure that this code is working.

Answer (score 7):

```
Math.round(parseFloat(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x/Dimensions.get('window').width));
```

Will solve your issue.

Answer (score 5):

Just a tip for those using `pagingEnabled`.

You can use `onMomentumScrollEnd`, which fires only when the scroll element has 'snapped' into position

```
  <Animated.ScrollView
    horizontal={true}
    pagingEnabled={true}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    onMomentumScrollEnd={(event) => console.log(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x)
  }}
```