# How to get scrollview index

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview

I am using react-native `scrollview` to `slide` my `imageBackground`.

I am using `pagingEnabled` to swipe the images. But is there a way I could get number of the `index` when ever I swipe?

I am using the scroll view like the code below. Adding `pagingEnabled` will make the scrollview work like a `swiper` but I don't know how to get the `index`.

```
<ScrollView horizontal={true} pagingEnabled={true}>
            {this.createScrollImageSources(this.state.image)}
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38799702/how-to-show-current-page-num-of-paging-scrollview does this help you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could make use of the [onScroll](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#onscroll) method together with the [Dimensions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions) module to calculate the currentScreenIndex.

### Example:

**render**

```
  <View style={styles.container}>
   <ScrollView pagingEnabled horizontal style={{flex: 1}} onScroll={(e)=>this.handleOnScroll(e)} scrollEventThrottle={5}>
     <View style={{width: SCREEN_WIDTH, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}} />
     <View style={{width: SCREEN_WIDTH, backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
     <View style={{width: SCREEN_WIDTH, backgroundColor: 'green'}} />
   </ScrollView>
  </View>
```

**handleOnScroll**

```
  handleOnScroll(event){
    //calculate screenIndex by contentOffset and screen width
    console.log('currentScreenIndex', parseInt(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x/Dimensions.get('window').width));
  }
```

### Working Demo

https://snack.expo.io/HyxzFr2HxU

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to use the `onScroll` prop to check the current offset of the horizontal scrollview. Then compare the current offset with your device width.

Try:

```
<ScrollView onScroll={this.handleScroll} />
```

And then:

```
handleScroll: function(event: Object) {
 console.log(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x);
},
```